# Webforms application fails in IFrame when accessed by IE9

Tags: c#, iframe, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have built a WebForms .NET app using TwitterBootstrap. The app is hosted on a separate domain to where it is actually used viz. apps.mydomain.com/appurl. The application is "embedded" into another website on its own domain viz www.someotherdomain.com via an IFrame. This works for all browsers (including other versions of IE) except for IE9 where the JavaScript stops responding on the page. If IE9 is used directly to apps.mydomain.com/appurl then it "just works".

I get no errors or access denied or anything else visible. Having read heaps of posts I have made sure that:

- Both doctypes are the same - in my case
- I have tried both `<sessionState cookieless="true" mode="InProc"></sessionState>` and `<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">` in my web.config with the same results

The script libraries being used are:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ezpz_hint.js"></script>
```

If anybody has got *any* ideas I would be glad to hear them as I have Googled this to death and cannot seem to find a solution. At this point I have to use the IFrame and IE9 needs to work so I ahve to find a solution. :-]

TIA

Comment: Is everything SSL?  You might try changing your links from `https://...` to just `//...`.

Comment: @gilly3: You sir are a legend!!! Changed all links to http and hey presto it all works. Much appreciated.

Comment: Seems I spoke too soon. I was inadvertently testing it outside of the IFrame and it worked. However within the IFrame (Within a Joomla CMS site) it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it was nice being a legend while it lasted. Without more detail, it's difficult to guess at.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't like it when a portion of your code is SSL, but not all.  A good habit to get into is to use [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) relative URLs by dropping the http/https from your links.  If a URL starts with `//`, the scheme of the current context will be used:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ezpz_hint.js"></script>
```

Comment: As I spoke too early and it does not work I tried your suggestion of schema relative and that did not work either. So I am back to square one. I wonder if it is a jQuery conflict? THat does not make sense as then all browsers should fail. Any other ideas?

Comment: OK. So it looks like its an access denied issue. When I try with IE8 I actually get some errors which are:

Message: Access is denied.

Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js


Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js


Message: Object expected
Code: 0
URI: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.js

and so on. So can anyone shed any light now?

Comment: You can't use jQuery 2.* with IE8. If you are supporting IE8, use jQuery 1.*.